# Presta shop layout broke down

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Normally my presta should look like this:
[working presta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xF27h.jpg),

And now it looks like this:
 [broken presta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQvGh.png).
It probably happend after this module installation:
Moduł Cookies v1.3.5 - by MyPresta.eu

I tried to disable it, remove it, reinstall it, but got no effect.
It seems, like there is an error in html parsing.

Does anybody know how to cope with that? Mayby in which file look for the answer?

Comment: If you have bought the module I'll suggest to ask to MyPresta.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your browser console that is there any javascipt error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be caused by the **CSS file in the browser cache**. Have you tried reloading with the <kbd>CTRL + F5</kbd> keys?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the css file is not loading,

Please check again the "header" hook in backend, it may be some modules are unhooked from the "header" hook.